# Open newInent and loadUrl from notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, push-notification

Ok I'm almost there. I have notifications coming but want to open the app and load a URL in the webview that I have when you click the notification. The code that I have is below. When I click the notification, it opens the webview activity but it then crashes and doesn't load the page.

This is my notification

```
private void sendGCMIntent(final Context theContext, Intent theMsg) 
    {   
        int icon = R.drawable.noti_msg, count;
        long when = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        String msg = theMsg.getStringExtra("message");
        String url = theMsg.getStringExtra("photo");
        count = Integer.parseInt(theMsg.getStringExtra("count"));
        Bitmap photo = getBitmapFromURL(url);
        String nameEncode = theMsg.getStringExtra("name");

        String theMessage = Html.fromHtml(msg).toString().replace("\\", "");
        String name = Html.fromHtml(nameEncode).toString();

        String title = theContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.msg);

        long[] vibraPattern = { 0, 500, 250, 500 };

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(theContext,MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+when));

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(theContext, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) theContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(theContext);

        notification.setContentTitle(title);
        notification.setContentText("New message from: "+ name);
        notification.setSubText(theMessage);
        notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notification.setTicker("New message");
        notification.setNumber(count);
        notification.setSmallIcon(icon);
        notification.setLargeIcon(photo);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        notification.setSound(soundUri);
        notification.setVibrate(vibraPattern);
        notification.setWhen(when);

        Notification notifies = notification.build();

        notificationManager.notify((int)when, notifies);    
    }
```

And in my MainActivity I have this

```
  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("message"))
        {
           String mUrl = intent.getStringExtra("mid");
           webView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        }
    }
```

Here are the log errors

```
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at me.site.test.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:230)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1168)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2181)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2194)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2203)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-15 07:33:41.061: E/AndroidRuntime(19851):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please include your logcat output. You say that it crashes, but you don't show us the Exception that is thrown when it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading a String Extra from your intent, but you are never setting this String Extra in `notificationIntent`.

I suspect that you're getting a `NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
if(intent.getStringExtra("type").equals("message"))
```

You really need to be calling:

```
notificationIntent.putExtra( "type", "message" );
notificationIntent.putExtra( "mid", /* some String value */ );
```

in your `sendGCMIntent` method.

Comment: Yes it's a nullpointerException. Ok so I need to change the onNewIntent method? I don't know the value of mid, so how would I extract that like I do in my notification method?

Comment: I take that back I don't get the string for mid in my notification method, but I do get message. I need to be able to check it and get the value of mid.

Comment: Being new to Java/Android it took me a while to get what you were saying. But that seems to have fixed the problems. Sometimes newbies need a bit more explanation. :)